# Kotlin: inherit from a nested Java class

Tags: java, inheritance, kotlin, nested

I have these Java classes in a *.java* file:

```
public class BaseOuter
{
    public class BaseInner
    {
    }
}
```

And I have these Kotlin classes in a *.kt* file:

```
class DerivedOuter : BaseOuter()
{
    class DerivedInner : BaseOuter.BaseInner()
    {
    }
}
```

This Kotlin code in Android Studio gives me an "Unresolved reference: BaseInner" error. So I can inherit from the BaseOuter class, but deriving from Java's BaseOuter.BaseInner is not syntactically correct (but if I try the same with inheritance from Kotlin classes I get no errors).

Somehow I can't google a same example or the question.

Comment: For one thing, this doesn't work, because you have an inner class in Java but a static member class in Kotlin. For a class to be *inner* in Kotlin, you need to mark it with the `inner` keyword: `inner class DerivedInner ...`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't think it would solve it (because the error says it can't resolve the reference which doesn't sound like the problem I mentioned) and I didn't have time to try it. Hence only a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of Java's non-static nested class in Kotlin is inner class.

To make your code work, you need to use `inner` keyword:

```
class DerivedOuter() : BaseOuter() {
    inner class DerivedInner : BaseOuter.BaseInner() {
    }
}
```